# Path for different dropbox-names

Tags: excel, vba, path, dropbox

I have a question regarding the path for a file in a dropbox folder in excel VBA:
Currently, I use

```
path = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\PVAP Dropbox\..."
```

I use

```
Environ("username")
```

because it has to work on multiple computers.

But is it also possible to make a changeable for the name of the dropbox? The name of our company dropbox is "PVAP Dropbox". But can I write the code so that it would work for another dropbox name? for example "ABC Dropbox" without having to change each path in the workbook manually.

in short: is there something in excel like this?

```
Environ("dropboxname")
```

Thx in advance

Comment: It may be possible from your local app data folder.  I dont have dropbox at work, so can't check that.

Comment: Is there a file called info.json

Comment: https://help.dropbox.com/en-en/installs-integrations/desktop/locate-dropbox-folder

Comment: the file info.json contains this:
{"business": {"path": "C:\\Users\\matti\\PVAP Dropbox\\Seppe Nijsen", "host": 67xxxxxxxxx, "is_team": true, "subscription_type": "Business", "root_path": "C:\\Users\\matti\\PVAP Dropbox"}}